# Navigation action/destination action cannot be found from the current destination

Tags: android, xml

I used navigation component in my app.
I uploaded my app to firebase to make a test.
app worked normally in the most of devices, but in some devices app crashed and show the error in this image

[image]

Here's my navigation file code

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
app:startDestination="@id/menuhome">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuhome"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_menuhome_to_menuDrugs"
        app:destination="@id/menuDrugs" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_menuhome_to_menudiseases"
        app:destination="@id/menudiseases" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_menuhome_to_menuDoseCalculator"
        app:destination="@id/menuDoseCalculator" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_menuhome_to_menuReferences"
        app:destination="@id/menuReferences" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menudiseases"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.DiseasesFragment"
    android:label="@string/diseases"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_diseases" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuDrugs"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.DrugsFragment"
    android:label="@string/drugs"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drugs" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuDoseCalculator"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.DoseCalculatorFragment"
    android:label="@string/DC"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dose_calculator" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuReferences"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.ReferencesFragment"
    android:label="@string/references"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_references" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuAboutUs"
    android:name="com.poultry.poultryscope.AboutFragment"
    android:label="@string/about_us"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
```

So why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: The route on the URL cannot be found or you do not have permission to the route (id/menuDrugs).

Comment: why app worked in some devices and crashed in others

Comment: The account being used.  Some machines the account is Admin and other not Admin.  An Admin would have permission to all files while normal user would not.

Answer (score 0):

double click is the cause of the crash.

I added if condition to handle the click for each item in the menu home and the problem was solved.

example for diseases click

```
if (navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() == R.id.menuhome) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_menuhome_to_menudiseases);
            }
```

and for drugs click

```
 if (navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() == R.id.menuhome) {

            navController.navigate(R.id.action_menuhome_to_menuDrugs);
```

[image]